# Can C and C++ style comments interact to the point of ambiguity?

Tags: c

Consider this line of C++ code:

```cpp
/* some comment *//* another comment */
```

Is this a valid line with 2 C comments? Or is it invalid because everything after `//` is C++ comment?

With gcc, it appears this is 2 C comments, probably because there was already the beginning of a C comment. But is there a word from C/C++ standards? There's operator precedence, but comments aren't operators, so I couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: I'd expect it'd find the `*/` and `/*` tokens correctly, either minimally or maximally here. Is there a comment valid in C but not in C++? Not in any current standard of each that I know of.

Comment: @tadman did you intentionally edit the text when you formatted? I thought OP was asking about `//` somewhere between `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: @yano I thought so too, but look at my edit. In the way it was presented initially, Markdown was hiding the inner `*` and lead to an entirely different interpretation of the question. At first I thought Stack Overflow was doing some VS Code-style auto-clean-up, but no.

Comment: @tadman ahhh, I see now. Yeah I totally missed that.

Comment: "_Consider this line of C++ code_": But then you tag `c`, not `c++`. Also "_But is there a word from C/C++ standards?_". The answer may be potentially different in the two languages, but asking about both at the same time is frowned upon as well, except if you are specifically interested in comparing aspects of the two languages. See the `c` and `c++` tag wikis.

Comment: _"Can C and C++ style comments interact to the point of ambiguity?"_ - This is one of the few times I'd argue for tagging with _both_ these language tags.

Answer (score 9):

The above is considered two separate comments.

Because there is a comment starting with `/*`, all text up to `*/` are part of the same comment.  Similarly, for a comment starting with `//` everything up to the next newline is part of the same comment.

This is spelled out in section 6.4.9 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding comments:

> *1* Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `/*` introduce a comment. **The contents of
> such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and
> to find the characters `*/` that terminate it.**
>
> *2* Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters `//` introduce a comment that includes all
> multibyte characters up to, but not including, the next new-line
> character. The contents of such a comment are examined only to
> identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line
> character.

The [C++ standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) has similar language in section 5.7:

> **The characters `/*` start a comment, which terminates with the
> characters `*/`.** These comments do not nest. The characters `//` start a
> comment, which terminates immediately before the next new-line
> character. If there is a form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such
> a comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it and the
> new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required. [
> *Note*: The comment characters `//`, `/*`, and `*/` have no special meaning
> within a `//` comment and are treated just like other characters.
> **Similarly, the comment characters `//` and `/*` have no special meaning
> within a `/*` comment.** — *end note* ]

So in the above code, as soon as `*/` is seen that marks the end of the first comment, then the `/*` that immediately follows starts the second comment.

More generally, both languages specify that the two comment types do not interfere with each other, and additionally that `/* ... */` style comments do not nest.  So there is no ambiguity.

Comment: dbush, This answer well addresses OP's sample `/* some comment *//* another comment */`, yet is incomplete in clearly answering "Can C and C++ style comments interact to the point of ambiguity (in any case) ?". (Which AFAICT is _no_).

Answer (score 2):

I think the rules themselves are straightforward. Everything from a `/*` to a `*/` is ignored, including other comments, which is why you can't nest comments, e.g:

```
/* Ignore this:
    a = b + c; /* Add */
   Now stop ignoring. */
```

This will look to the compiler like:

```
   Now stop ignoring. */
```

...and will fail.

Similarly `//` will ignore any comment start:

```
    // a = b + c;  /* Add them,
                      this is important later. */
```

The compiler will see:

```
                      this is important later. */
```

Also text in strings can cause problems:

```
/* Skip
    printf("Type */* to select all\n");
*/
```

Will compile as:

```
* to select all\n");
*/
```

If that's the interaction you were wondering about, yes, you have to be careful about it.

Comment: These are good examples of how comments can be sometimes less than intuitive, though I can seem how it's all valid.